# Drupal Custom Page URL

Tags: url, drupal, module

I found a good guide to create Drupal Module. (URL below)
http://webemania.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-module-in-drupal-in-three-easy-steps

But I would like to know which part of the code specify the url localhost/drupal6/person.
Cos' I have a code of myself with 'checkperson' as the module folder but the URL is localhost/drupal/check_person

I don't understand how it was created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `hook_menu` part of the code,they have defined an `$items['person']`.The argument inside the `$items` refers to the url  `localhost/drupal6/person`.The definition for each path may include a page callback function, which is invoked when the `registered path` is requested.For example, your module could `register path 'person'`.When path `'person'` is requested, the `page callback function` will called.For more info try reading the [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) mate.. :)

Note:Try clearing ur `cache` once u have added a new menu item

Comment: Thanks mate! Yea I clear my cache and i changed the hook_menu part from $items['person'] to $items['check_person'] and from there I am able to use the URL check_person. :)